# Route not working properly with htaccess in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created my application using laravel and vue.js and hosted my application on server in subfolder inside public_html,
Accessing it using url like this:

> https://maindomain.in/projectfolder/public/login

but after login if i click on any link it points back to

https://maindomain.in/dashboard

and i get 404 not found in console for the api routes that are accessed  for eg. accessing dashboard

> https://maindomain.in/api/backend/get-dashboatd-data

My root htaccess file content is :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Remove public folder form URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

> Note: Frontend is in Vue.js and backend in laravel.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like your web server is not pointing to the right folder.

Laravel expects you to serve the project from the `public` folder inside the project's root directory.

You're serving it from the main `apache/nginx` folder. That's why you need to add the subfolder and public folders in the URL to visit the website.

Check the [Laravel Nginx configuration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#nginx) example to notice the `root` directory they're specifying.

Answer (score -1):

Your nginx/apache server is configured wrong

You must point nginx/apache to the folder

**/var/www/XXX_PROJECT_XXX/**